# Set folder based on folder index

Tags: operating-system

I am trying to create an os path based on the partial folder name.

the folder structure looks like this:

1. January
2. February
3. March
   etc

i've set up the `folder_path` to the parent directory, and are looking to set the `current_folder` to something like this: `current_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, year, month)`
where month is the folder name, split by "." and index [0]

How can i get the indexed month back to the folder name the most efficient?

The next steps are to set a previous month, then loop through all the sub-folders in each month and compare them to the previous month:

```
previous_folder = os.path.join(folder_path, year, previous_month)
```

```
for folder in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    current_file = os.path.join(current_folder, folder, "prodA")
    previous_file = os.path.join(previous_folder, folder, "prodA")
```